# Is it possible to copy data from one Ansible Tower to another?

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

I am attempting to copy all the data (templates, credentials, inventories, etc) from my Ansible Tower production instance to my newly created dev instance. Is there a way to do this automatically using an ansible API? I have attempted to research [tower-cli](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/3.5.3/html/towerapi/tower_cli.html) but there doesn't seem to be much information on this use case. Additionally, tower-cli looks to be deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no - you can use `tower-cli` to receive (backup) and send (restore) the configuration. See https://www.unixarena.com/2019/03/backup-restore-ansible-awx-tower-cli.html/

```
tower-cli receive --all >  config.json
tower-cli send config.json
```

But - there is no way to backup the credentials. The receive command doesnt export them.

All possible options are documented https://tower-cli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ but not very good. I found the command line help within `tower-cli help` a bit easier to understand.

Also - development is no longer under development. So, be aware that the new client is awxkit. See https://github.com/ansible/awx/tree/devel/awxkit/awxkit/cli/docs - it has the same parameters.

I've got also the answer: make a backup of the AWX database and recover them to the new database (or reuse it) together with the new AWX instance. But I'm not sure, if this is really a 'good' recommended solution.